# How set permissions for create action in rest_framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to set perissions for the create action (post). And I dont know hot to do it.

This is my code:

In permissions.py

```
class IsAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, category):
        if request.user.role == "admin":
            return request.user.role == "admin"
        return False
```

In view

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

```
queryset = Category.objects.all()
serializer_class = CategorySerializer

def get_permissions(self):
    if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return (permissions.DjangoModelPermissions(),)
    return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAdmin(),)
```

Answer (score -1):

Already, I have solved it, just i've change in my permissions.py file, the method:

```
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, category):
    if request.user.role == "admin":
        return request.user.role == "admin"
    return False
```

for this method:

```
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.user.role == "admin":
        return request.user.role == "admin"
    return False
```

It's Simple, i complicate too much